# How to call a function of a plugin from outside of that plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, jquery-plugins

I know this is an old question in stackoverflow. But for me it is new, I have searched for a solution but I didn't got a solution which I can understand. I have a plugin, in that I have some functions. Now I want to access one of the function when an event changes on `select options`. But my problem is I'm not able access the function from outside of the plugin. However I'm new to plugin development.

here is my plugin :

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    var Spec = {
        init: function(options, ele) 
        {
            var self = this;
            self.elem = ele;
            self.$elem = $(ele);

            self.findPro = (typeof options === 'string') ? self.findPro = options : self.findPro = options.findPro;
            self.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.specpro.options, options);
            if (self.options.findPro === 'latest') {
                self.latestPro();
            }
        },
        .
        .
        .
        filter:function(filFor){
            console.log($('.chzn-select').val());

        }
    };
    $.fn.specpro = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var spec = Object.create(Spec);
            spec.init(options, this);
        });
    };
    $.fn.specpro.options = {
        findPro: 'latest'
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

And what I tried is :

```
$(function(){
 var mn=$('#lp').specpro({findPro:'latest'});
 $('.chzn-select').chosen().change().mn.filter('latest');
});
```

Can anyone tell me. How can I call the function `filter` from outside of the plugin.

Live [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywL9e/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The function is in the "Spec" object and that is inside the scope of self-invoking anonymous function:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
... code ...
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

So only code inside that anonymous function can access `Spec.filter()`. To access the Spec variable it would need to be in the global scope.

When something is in "global" scope this means it is attached to the global object (In most every case this is window).

So for example

```
var test = {
'hello' : function (){
    alert('hello world');
    }
}
```

Is functionally the same as as:

```
window.test = {
'hello' : function (){
    alert('hello world');
    }
}
```

So it they both could be called as test.hello() or window.test.hello() The 'test' object is in global scope (window).

Now lets put the first example in an anonymous function.

```
(function(){
var test = {
'hello' : function (){
    alert('hello world');
    }
}
// call the function
test.hello();

})();
```

If you try this it will show the alert. But if you tired to call `test.hello();` later on, you will get something like:

> ReferenceError: test is not defined

The object test and its hello() function is in the anonymous functions scope, not the global scope.

Now here is the same function again, but we are attaching test directly to window (the global scope).

```
(function(){
window.test = {
'hello' : function (){
    alert('hello world');
    }
}
// call the function
test.hello();

})();
```

Now you can test.hello() outside the anonymous function at any later time. You can have many levels of scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, I have attached it to the `window` but again it is showing the same error. Can you update your example in **fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/ywL9e/2/